# Cannot retrieve conrete data from sql with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

i am coding some filter of data, but i have a problem. Cannot get data, not sure whats wrong. I have been trying this for 5 hours now.

This is my code:

```
var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();

            //select records
            var dok = await context.Dok
            .Where(x => x.Data == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2) && x.TypDok == 21)
            .ToListAsync();

            // Define the DokId (column name) range from dok
            var dokIdRange = dok.Select(x => x.DokId);

            //select records containing dokId
            var pozDok = await context.PozDok
                          .Where(x => dokIdRange.Contains(x.DokId))
                         .ToListAsync();

            //group them and count
            var result = (
                    from pd in pozDok
                    group pd by pd.TowId into g
                    select new
                    {
                        TowId = g.Key,
                        IloscPlusSum = g.Sum(x => x.IloscPlus)
                    }
                ).ToList();
```

Do you have any ideas whats wrong?

this is case:
I get records for specific date from table named dok,
then i check dokid range.
after that i call table named pozdok and gets all records containing dokid from dokidrange.
After that i need to make towid into 1 object and add all iloscplus counts. (There can be 3x towid object, i need to make it as one with iloscplus = count for 3 of them.)

##UPDATE

here Dok and PozDok classess:

```
    public class Dok
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public decimal DokId { get; set; }
    public decimal UzId { get; set; }
    public decimal MagId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public int KolejnyWDniu { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataDod { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataPom { get; set; }
    public string NrDok { get; set; }
    public short TypDok { get; set; }
    public short Aktywny { get; set; }
    public short Opcja1 { get; set; }
    public short Opcja2 { get; set; }
    public short Opcja3 { get; set; }
    public short Opcja4 { get; set; }
    public short CenyZakBrutto { get; set; }
    public short CenySpBrutto { get; set; }
    public short FormaPlat { get; set; }
    public short TerminPlat { get; set; }
    public short PoziomCen { get; set; }
    public decimal RabatProc { get; set; }
    public decimal Netto { get; set; }
    public decimal Podatek { get; set; }
    public decimal NettoUslugi { get; set; }
    public decimal PodatekUslugi { get; set; }
    public decimal NettoDet { get; set; }
    public decimal PodatekDet { get; set; }
    public decimal NettoDetUslugi { get; set; }
    public decimal PodatekDetUslugi { get; set; }
    public decimal NettoMag { get; set; }
    public decimal PodatekMag { get; set; }
    public decimal NettoMagUslugi { get; set; }
    public decimal PodatekMagUslugi { get; set; }
    public decimal Razem { get; set; }
    public decimal DoZaplaty { get; set; }
    public decimal Zaplacono { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota3 { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota4 { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota5 { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota6 { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota7 { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota8 { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota9 { get; set; }
    public decimal Kwota10 { get; set; }
    public int Param1 { get; set; }
    public int Param2 { get; set; }
    public int Param3 { get; set; }
    public int Param4 { get; set; }
    public short EksportFK { get; set; }
    public DateTime Zmiana { get; set; }
    public int? NrKolejny { get; set; }
    public int? NrKolejnyMag { get; set; }
    public int? Param5 { get; set; }
    public int? Param6 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Kwota11 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Kwota12 { get; set; }
    public int? WalId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Kurs { get; set; }
    public decimal? CentrDokId { get; set; }
    public short? Opcja5 { get; set; }
    public short? Opcja6 { get; set; }
    public short? Opcja7 { get; set; }
    public short? Opcja8 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ZmianaPkt { get; set; }
    public decimal? ZaplaconoPodatek { get; set; }
    public decimal? ZaplaconoWKasie { get; set; }
}




public class PozDok
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public decimal DokId { get; set; }
    public int Kolejnosc { get; set; }
    public int NrPozycji { get; set; }
    public decimal TowId { get; set; }
    public short TypPoz { get; set; }
    public decimal IloscPlus { get; set; }
    public decimal IloscMinus { get; set; }
    public short PoziomCen { get; set; }
    public short Metoda { get; set; }
    public decimal CenaDomyslna { get; set; }
    public decimal CenaPrzedRab { get; set; }
    public decimal RabatProc { get; set; }
    public decimal CenaPoRab { get; set; }
    public decimal Wartosc { get; set; }
    public decimal CenaDet { get; set; }
    public decimal CenaMag { get; set; }
    public short Stawka { get; set; }
    public short TypTowaru { get; set; }
    public decimal IleWZgrzewce { get; set; }
    public short? StawkaDod { get; set; }
    public decimal? Netto { get; set; }
    public decimal? Podatek { get; set; }
}
```

I need to filter Dok by Data and i get list of DokId.

Now i need to filter PozDok by DokId list and i get list of results.

Now i need to join by TowId (many TowId) and sum their IloscPlus

Comment: You didn't describe any problem. The code is definitely problematic though. EF is an ORM - *Object* to Relational Mapper. It's meant to let you work with *Objects*, not tables. `Dok` and `PozDok` are supposed to be the names of your application's classes, not table names. There's no reason to read the ID *properties* from `Dok` (whatever that is) to find the related `PozDok` *objects* (whatever *those* are). If the entities have proper relations and navigation properties, EF itself will load both the root and the related objects.

Comment: In the [Blogs and Posts example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) used in most EF tutorials, the Blog *class* has a `Posts` collection property. If you write` var myBlog=context.Blog.Inculde(b=>b.Posts).Where(b=>b.BlogId=someID)` EF will generate a JOIN query that loads both the Blog object and all related Posts

Comment: If you wanted to sum the ratings of an author's posts, you could write `context.Posts.Where(p=>p.Blog.Author.Name="blah").Sum(p=>p.Ratings)`. EF will join the Posts, Blogs and Authors table, filter by author name ang SUM the post ratings. You can use `GroupBy` eg by category to generate a GROUP BY too. There's no need to start from the Authors or Blogs table when you really want to aggregate Posts

Comment: Dok and PozDok are two tables. In Dok i get DokId and after in PozDok is column DokId which can help me filter out data for specific date. Then i need to group by TowId (join them into 1) and sum their iloscplus number

Comment: I repeat - ORMs deal with objects. Not tables. Those are *objects with properties*. You're once again reciting/describing the code. The code is wrong

Comment: Ok, so tell me please how i can get it done?

Comment: I already explained that in the comments. Given the unusual names I can't guess what these things are, or what you're trying to calculate. Objects and classes should have meaningful names. I gave examples how to load a blog's posts, how to sum the ratings of all of an author's posts, no matter the blog. Since you're grouping, you can add `GroupBy` eg post categories with `context.Posts.Where(p=>p.Blog.Author.Name="blah").GroupBy(p=>p.Category).Select(g=>new {Category=g.Key,Totals=g.Sum(p=>p.Ratings)});`

Comment: Man, Dok and PozDok are 2 tables which i have as classes to read them into C# object.

Comment: You should start from an EF Core tutorial [like the Quick start in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli).

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You need to filter Dok via date for specific DokId and then take these DokID and filter them in PozDok and then you get list of results. Now you need to group them and thats it, but i cannot get it.

Comment: If you dont want to help, or try to find a way out please do not spam.

Comment: Where are those classes? Why do you even assume you need to filter the related classes instead of using the relation properties *which should be there*? Assuming `Dok` is a class, it should have a `Pozes` property. If it does, EF will load those objects automatically, there's no need for the second query

Comment: `If you dont want to help` if you want people to help, post the minimum information needed. Don't make people guess: a clear description of the problem (what *is* it that doesn't work?), sample data, expected outcome, the actual classes, table schemas, DbContext configuration and relations. I suspect once you do this you'll get the same answers I already posted. Also check [How to Ask a Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Class Dok has DokId, but class PozDok also has DokId (these are two different tables which contains info about each other).

From Dok i get list of DokId and from PozDok i get list of TowId (itemId) for specific date but PozDok also has column TowId (itemId) and IloscPlus (count).

Comment: Post the code *in the question itself*. Don't describe it. We can't compile descriptions. Post something we can write in a C# file or run in DotnetFiddle.

Comment: done, classess are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct answer! :) I fixed that by myself:)

```cs
var q = (from dok1 in context.Dok
          .Where(a => a.Data >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7))
            from pozDok2 in context.PozDok
              .Where(a => a.DokId == dok1.DokId)
            group pozDok2 by pozDok2.TowId into g
            select new {
              TowId = g.Key,
              IloscPlusSum = g.Sum(x => x.IloscPlus)
            }
         ).ToList();
```